# routing rest calls between microservices using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am currently working on a project where we have multiple microservices on the server side. Which microservices are available to the client changes constantly, as do the location they are available on.
To keep all these changes away from the client, I am working on a REST Router. This would be a single microservice on which knows where each of the other microservices is located. The client can then just talk to this router microservice which will send the request to the correct endpoint.

While this should be fairly straight forward in my opinion, I'm running into al sorts of problems. Since the microservices don't necessarily live on the same host, the router can't simple forward the call, since this only works within the same host.

I am currently trying to make it work by sending a redirect back to the client containing the correct endpoint URL in the location header. But when I try this through restlet, I get a 404 instead of the expected 307 with the location header.

Here's my router code:

```
@Path("/{any : .*}")
public Response forward(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Response response = null;
    String requestUri = request.getRequestURI().toString();
    String actualUri = requestUri.substring(requestUri.indexOf("route") + 6);
    String endpointId = actualUri.substring(0, actualUri.indexOf('/'));
    try {
        response = redirectTo("http://localhost:8181/api/user/available");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = Response.serverError().status(500).build();
    }
    return response;
}

private Response redirectTo(String path) {
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(path);
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should work. When I debug the code, I can see that the created Response contains the 307 HTTP status, and the correct location header. But in the client test application (Restlet in Chrome) I keep hitting the 404. When I point restlet directly at the http://localhost:8181/api/user/available I do get the expected result, so the endpoint is available and responding on that address.

Can anyone point me out where I'm going wrong here? Is this really a server issue, or am I missing something in my client software?

Comment: The recommended approach here is to make use of a micro-service registry like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), [Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) etc to keep track of your micro-services and use a software load balancer client like [Ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon) which communicates with these registries and then route the requests to appropriate micro-service instances. A client redirect is not a scalable solution in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. But using something like Eureka would mean I would have a way for my router service to determine where to forward the client request to. Since the client is the web-browser of the user, I can't very well expose all those middle tier services directly to the outside world, If I read Eureka right. The question then remains, how to forward a request from one rest service to another, on a different host. The request dispatcher you would normally use for forwarding only supports same host forwarding.